# Changing colour of $success message in php

Tags: php, html, css

How do I change the colour of 'Work Successfully Deleted!' when displayed on my website through this code...

```
$success = "Work Successfully Deleted!";
```

I have attempted this in my **create.php**.

```
<span class= "alert alert-success" role="alert">Assignment Tracked Successfully!</span></p>
```

and works perfectly.

However my **delete.php** seems a little different. I am aware you can't directly insert the above code into certain statements.

Comment: What have you tried, show us your best attempt (code). Do you get any error(s)? Please read [ask].

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with how things are displayed. You're probably looking for CSS rules. Here's a [good starting tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/First_steps/Getting_started).

Comment: Something like this? `$success = "<span style='color:red;'>Work Successfully Deleted!</span>"`

Comment: Hi @jibsteroos I am very new to coding, I have attempted this in my create.php. <span class= "alert alert-success" role="alert">Assignment Tracked Successfully!</span></p> and works perfectly. However my delete.php seems a little different. I am aware you can't directly insert the above code into certain statements. I should have been more clear, thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud use HTML and CSS to do this. You can output desired content with PHP by something like `$success = '<span style="color:green;">Work Successfully Deleted!</span>'`.